# Java repaint() flick

Tags: java, swing, netbeans

i have a custom paint method in java

```
@Override
public void paint(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponents(g);
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) buffer.getGraphics(); 
    g2.setColor(java.awt.Color.WHITE);
    g2.fillRect(0, 0, jPanel1.getWidth(), jPanel1.getHeight());
    //paint some custom graphic forms
    g2 = (Graphics2D) jPanel1.getGraphics();
    g2.drawImage(buffer, 0, 0, jPanel1.getWidth(), jPanel1.getHeight(), null);

}
```

and when the user drag the mouse i update the position of the graphic forms and call

repaint();
at the end of the method

My problem is that the forms update correctly but there is a annoying flick. How can i solve the flick? thanks in advance

Answer (score -2, accepted):

simply use this repaint:

repaint(0, 0, 1, 1);

instead of yours

Comment: This answer would be much more useful if you explained a little bit why you think it will solve the problem.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#repaint(int,%20int,%20int,%20int)

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible to answer this question well without seeing more code, preferably a [minimal compilable, runnable example program or MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) but I can make suggestions:

- If you're drawing within a top-level window such as a JFrame, JApplet or similar, don't.
- You should not be calling a super painting method that is different from the overridden one. Here you're calling `super.paintComponents` within a paint method, a **very** dangerous thing to do.
- You should draw within a JPanel's paintComponent method as this will automatically grant you double buffering.
- And as noted above, should be calling `super.paintComponent` within the override.
- You should avoid using Graphics objects obtained by calling `getGraphics()` on a Swing GUi component since this gives you an object which is short-lived, and this risks your image disappearing or worse, a NullPointerException being thrown.